# how to remove shared preference while application uninstall in android

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have an android application to save the login details such as user name and password via `SharedPreferences` thats works fine, but i need to remove all my used `SharedPreferences` while my application uninstall. How to do it?

```
SavePreferences("one ", "");
SavePreferences("two", "");
LoadPreferences();

 private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("TEST", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
   }

 private void LoadPreferences(){
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("TEST", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM1", "");
    String strSavedMem2 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM2", "");   
   }
```

I want to remove this `SharedPreferences` when my application uninstall.

Comment: This will be removed automatically by Android OS on application uninstall...

Comment: thanks for the worthful detail

Comment: Not on my rooted Samsung Galaxy 1 (Froyo). Still remained in `/dbdata/database/my.package/shared_prefs`. Don't know if this is beacuse it's rooted or because it's Froyo. Haven't been able to test with newer devices

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` is always deleted along with the app uninstall.

When you uninstall any application all the changes the application have made in your internal memory are revoked, that means your SharedPreference files, Other data files, Database file, Application gets removed automatically by the Android OS.

***EDITED: 29/04/15: for >= 21 API refer [@Maher Abuthraa 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35296675/1168654)***

Comment: Not the case on Nexus 6P, figuring this out right now.

Comment: Yes, I also observed in Nexus 5 running with Android 6 is not deleting the sharedpreferences. I had to restart the device after uninstall and the sharedpreferences is gone now

Comment: @AndyRoid: i don't think its happening. i have nexus 5 with 6.1.1 its never happning. still you can search in bug list https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/ if there is no bug related to this then add new bug so they resolve its as soon as possible.

Comment: Galaxy s7 here with the same problem. I Uninstall and after install the sharedpreferences are still set. Really annoying because I can't test fresh installs by just uninstalling it.

Comment: @Maher Abuthraa has a right answer this answer is wrong.

Comment: Galaxy s6 edge. and has the same issue. does not remove the values in the preference file. Should try @Maher 's answer

Comment: technically this answer is correct, the preferences do get deleted, but on 21+ with backup enabled, the preferences are restored after install

Comment: Samsung s8 s8+ device as well not delete shared preference, I recently test. Really disappointed with Samsung

Answer (score 361):

The problem is not with preferences. It's drastically **the backup manager**! .. since android-23 by default backup as a task stores app's data including preferences to cloud. Later when you uninstall then install newer version you are probably going to use restored preferences. To avoid that, just add this to your manifest (or at least to debug manifest):

```
<application ...
        android:allowBackup="false">
...
</application>
```

Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

You will also see that if you run Lint under `Android > Lint > Security`:

[image: lint warning on backup]

It's good to mention here that the process of backup is like a blackbox .. you don't know when it starts, and period between checks ... so better for developing to disable it.

==== Update ====

You may get Manifest merger issues after setting `allowbackup` to `false`. To fix that issue add:

```
tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
```

in the application element. 
Credit to @shahzain-ali

Alternatively you can clear cache before uninstalling app.

I hope that may help.

Comment: Hey, I have noticed that in some devices the shared preferences is retained after unistall util the device is restarted. Is that connected to this? If so is it safe to set this flag to false on production apps? Will it affect the user?

Comment: Its not recommended to set false on production .. user will lose all preferences during update .. Better on production to migrate data if it necessary .. in debug code and preferences may change many times where is better to turn backup off

Comment: Kudos @MaherAbuthraa .. I was facing this issue of certain shared preference data being retained after app uninstall and reinstall. Never knew that such a thing was being done.

Comment: How can I make sure preferences are preserved during update but removed on manual uninstall? Surely this would be the expected behaviour.

Comment: @Gannet Preferences would have been removed after uninstallation . but might be restored from cloud later .. It's ultimately different from what's happening during upgrading app. when App being updated, system keeps preferences.To achieve your goal, just set that command above and your app will never restore preferences after uninstalling app.

Comment: @MaherAbuthraa thanks for the answer. I'm still a little confused though because you mentioned above that it isn't recommended to do this on production because the user will lose all preferences during update. Here's what I understand so far: 1. Prefs will always be removed after uninstall, regardless of allowBackup. 2. Prefs may be restored from cloud on reinstall, if allowBackup is true (personally I don't think this is appropriate). 3. Updates... not sure.

Comment: @Gannet. lets start from issue that devices powered with Android-23+ might restored preferences after reinstall (not upgrade). Generally its issue with developers and QA. Because preferences might be changing frequently and developers expect that preferences will be lost during reinstalling. Thats why its recommend to disable backup on debug only. that in case app doesn't have backup configuration. In production,  app should have migration plan how to move from earlier version of Preferences to newer one which is not really good practices to do so with debug versions during developing. clear ?

Comment: Even though I kept `android:allowBackup="false"` and `tools:replace="android:allowBackup"` still getting my preferences, Any idea what's the issue?

Comment: @ShylendraMadda Check if you have this one specific phone or generally. you can try this attrib "fullBackupContent".  some manufactures add backup-apps that don't respect attrib "android:allowBackup" . I would say for these kind of scenarios: go aggressively and clear the cache on the first launch of app for that particular phone if it's that critical issue.

Comment: I swear I had done this before.... after testing on a new phone I went back and the code was turned to true.... very very weird.

Answer (score 19):

Its strange but I found the solution in following way:

1. Add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in **manifest tag** of **Manifest.xml** file
2. Add `android:allowBackup="false"` in **application tag** of **Manifest.xml** file
3. Add `tools:replace="android:allowBackup"` in **application tag** of **Manifest.xml** file

**Manifest.xml** file should looks like this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--suppress ALL -->
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="com.package">

        // Other code

    <application
        android:name="com.package.Application"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="@string/application_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">

        <activity
            android:name="com.package.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/application_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        // Other code

    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Its done.

Comment: Your issue was one of your modules/AARs has android:allowBackup="true" .. That's why you need to set it up again with attribute tools:replace.

Comment: Even though I kept `android:allowBackup="false"` and `tools:replace="android:allowBackup"` still getting my preferences, Any idea what's the issue?

Comment: I am also getting the same issue. After adding this code not able to clear prefrence

Answer (score 11):

The problem is not with preferences.

use this code for fix it..........

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"></application>
```

Comment: That helped. By the way why don't we set allowbackup to false?

Comment: @shakle when you uninstall then install newer version you are probably going to use restored preferences. To avoid that, just add this to your manifest

Answer (score 5):

Setting `allowBackup="false"` opts an application out of both backup and restore.

```
 android:allowBackup="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

Shared Preferences do not always get deleted anymore as of marshmallow. Add this line in your  manifest: "android:allowBackup="false""