# Android Deep Link (with app uninstalled but left data in device)

Tags: android, deep-linking

I set deep link in my Android app but I found that if user uninstalled app without clear all data, the device show alert

Alert shown in device:

[image: (Alert shown in device)]

for app installation instead of open link in browser.Is there any method to open link in browser if user uninstall app even data is not yet cleared?

Target Flow:

[image: (Target Flow)]

Comment: Are u using firebase dynamic link for deep linking ?

Comment: Sorry, no, I am just using normal deep linking method, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue a while back, in my case I resolved the problem by setting manifest allowBackup to false (default is true):

```
android:allowBackup="false"
```

This may have other implications to your app? Worth reading the material around allowBackup.

Comment: I think its really only applicable to api 23+. Have you read through this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873066/how-to-remove-shared-preference-while-application-uninstall-in-android

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I am using api 23+ and I am quite sure I have successfully set allowBackup to false as other data has been removed, but the problem still here.

Comment: The above SO post discusses how to manage prefs to help avoid a scenario similar to your own. I'm guessing that when a user uninstalls the app not all prefs are deleted therefore when reinstalling the app already has e.g. login detail, etc. It may be that you need to change how your storing certain prefs to resolve the install issue you mention (the link I gave discusses just that). With the limited info on your app its hard to help any further.